# Discard changes option is not working in my project for some .robot file

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, version-control, robotframework

I worked on many projects but never ever faced this problem earlier. The problem is that if I click on the discard changes to the file, it automatically changes to its earlier version and shows again. If take a fresh copy from the remote and open the project and comes to the source control tab these four files also reflect by default that I changed something in that file. But actually, I didn't even touch those I tried too many times but no result. I attached the gif here for better understanding. please take a look in to the gif

[image: after clicking revert again coming back].

can anyone please help me on this.
Here particularly I have the problem with `charge_time.robot` , `Accuracy.robot` , `linearity.robot` , `Flow_and_volume.robot`

Comment: In Git, the word "revert" means something else, and since this question is tagged with Git, to avoid confusion I suggest you avoid using that word and instead say something like "Discard Changes" which is what that button is called in VS Code.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, but in other code editor also it is behaving the same such as PyCharm and eclipse.

Comment: How long after you undo the change are the files re-written? My guess is something on your machine is doing it, other than Git.